# Find row in dataframe including index and output as an arrray

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Simple Example with df dataframe:

```
df=

    A    B    C
0  1.4 -0.2 -1.9
1 -0.2 -0.3  0.1
2  0.5 -0.6  0.2
3  1.9  0.4  1.9
```

I want now to generate the desired output in array form of a specific row, for example the first row:

```
out = [0, 1.4, -0.2, -1.9]
```

With `df.values[0]` I get the first data row in an array form, but loose the index:

```
out = [1.4, -0.2, -1.9]
```

Is there a command to generate directly the desired output?

Comment: Is it `df.iloc[0]`? Or `df.reset_index().values[0]`?

Comment: IIUC, that's the definition if `iloc`

Comment: `df.iloc[0]` is a pandas series and also includes the headers (A,B,C) and      `df.reset_index().values[0]` looks good, but is an ndarray object

Comment: `list(df.reset_index().values[0])`?